# SyslogAppender not working in windows

Tags: java, logging, log4j, syslog

i used the following code without using lo4j.properites,but it not working,no logs are added in to the Systems log .
i am using windows platform.

public class SysLogApp extends SyslogAppender {

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    try {
        System.out.println("Start");
        Logger myLogger = Logger.getLogger("LoggerAppenderSyslog");
        System.out.println(myLogger);
        SysLogApp syslogAppender = new SysLogApp();
        myLogger.addAppender(syslogAppender);
        syslogAppender.setName("SYSTEM_SYSLOG");
        syslogAppender.setLayout(new PatternLayout("%d{MMM dd HH:mm:ss} %F %L %5p [%t] %m %n"));
        syslogAppender.setFacility("SYSLOG");
        syslogAppender.setFacilityPrinting(true);
        syslogAppender.setSyslogHost("localhost");
        System.out.println(syslogAppender.getName());
        syslogAppender.activateOptions();
        Logger.getRootLogger().addAppender(syslogAppender);
        myLogger.warn(" HEllo TEST ");
        System.out.println("End");
    } catch (Exception exc) {
        System.out.println("Exception " + exc);
    }
}
```

}

Answer (score 0, accepted):

i had done this by using NTEventLogAppender in log4j.
https://logging.apache.org/log4j/1.2/apidocs/org/apache/log4j/nt/NTEventLogAppender.html